# Is there a decent alternative to Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: xml, rss, feed, yahoo-pipes

Pipes is being very buggy lately and has stopped saving new pipes these days. 
Google Mashup Editor and Microsoft Popfly are both discontinued. 
Are there are any currently running web apps(or atleast libraries that run on appengine) that do something similar ?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019887/alternatives-to-yahoo-pipes

Comment: no duplicate: that of is about "alternatives running on my own server"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(This question has been asked several times...n For example:
[Yahoo Pipes clone script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425413/yahoo-pipes-clone-script)
[Alternatives to Yahoo Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019887/alternatives-to-yahoo-pipes)
)

Pipe2py is a compiler script that will generate a Python equivalent of a Yahoo Pipe given the URL of the pipe:

https://github.com/ggaughan/pipe2py/

(Note that not all Pipes blocks have yet been implemented.)

A "hosted" version of Pipe2Py is also available on Google App Engine: http://pipes-engine.appspot.com/

You might also find YQL [ http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ ] and Scraperwiki [ http://scraperwiki.com/ ] useful

Comment: Sure it has but in the future relative to the day I posted this question. Do check the dates. Thanks for the answer, no irony :)

Answer (score 5):

**[Dapper](http://open.dapper.net/)** seems pretty good, not as flexible but it's easier to parse data.

Comment: dapper also seems to be owned/operated by yahoo - not sure how this would be a suitable alternative

Comment: @messedup: Not sure why the downvote, Dapper was acquired by Yahoo! on 05 Oct 2010 (http://www.dapper.net/news/?p=1208), a couple of months after I wrote this.

Comment: Fair enough - i only downvoted because it seemed like there were better answers available.

Comment: @messedup: I also agree, I was unaware of those new OSS.

Answer (score 2):

try [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), the Yahoo! Query Language.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://superfeedr.com/ It's not exactly like pipes as it doesn't cache any data, but you can easily define work flows where the data from feeds is pushed to you.

Answer (score 0):

The unstopable 'upgrade' to verion II of YP is causing more than a few problems, hopefully it will settle down soon. My site has already ceased functioning as a result.

Am in the process of recreating my pipes using PYTHON on the Google Apps Engine, it's not as friendly as pipes but should be more stable. Very similiar to raw PHP but with sublte quirks and definitely not for beginers. I'm reasonably good with php and finding it steep learning curve, but there is nothing else credible out there.

Answer (score 0):

I used Yahoo Pipes to be able to requets RSS feeds from other websites using AJAX.

Now that Pipes is not working, I have used [`cors-anywhere`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere) to develop my own cors-proxy. It would take you 10-15 minutes to get your own version ready. You can find my implementation [here](https://github.com/remojansen/my-cors-proxy)

Once you have it ready in a GitHub repository you can deploye the repo from Github to Azure in just 5 minutes following [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/).

Then you will be able to request a feed via ajax, for example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/606821
```

Can be requested using:

```
http://my-cors-proxy.azurewebsites.net/stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/606821
```

> Note: You just need to replace the azure's website URL with your own one:
>
> http://my-cors-proxy.azurewebsites.net/

The URL above can only be invoked from `remojansen.com` because it was configured that way using the [`cors-anywhere`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere) `originWhitelist` setting:

```
originWhitelist: (process.env.PORT ? ['http://www.remojansen.com'] : []),
```

I hope my answer will help some people with my problem.