# Yahoo Pipes clone script?

Tags: feed, yahoo-pipes

Yahoo Pipes lack of processing power and cannot works well with website from far east. I need to process complex regex from far multiple locations, hundreds of posts every minutes, which Yahoo Pipes fail to generate the result.

Is there any codes or script act like Yahoo Pipes which I can use it in my own server?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe2py is a compiler script that will generate a Python equivalent of a Yahoo Pipe given the URL of the pipe:

https://github.com/ggaughan/pipe2py/

(Note that not all Pipes blocks have yet been implemented.)

A "hosted" version of Pipe2Py is also available on Google App Engine: http://pipes-engine.appspot.com/

Answer (score -1):

My inclination would be to use something like LWP with Perl

http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP