# .NET alternatives to Yahoo Pipes

Tags: .net, yahoo-pipes

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019887/alternatives-to-yahoo-pipes), except .NET alternatives instead.

---

<sup>Excerpt rom http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/:</sup>

**About Pipes**

Pipes is a powerful composition tool to aggregate, manipulate, and mashup content from around the web.

Like Unix pipes, simple commands can be combined together to create output that meets your needs:

- combine many feeds into one, then sort, filter and translate it.
- geocode your favorite feeds and browse the items on an interactive
  map.
- power widgets/badges on your web site.
- grab the output of any Pipes as RSS, JSON, KML, and other formats.

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer to the question you linked to, links to a python script generator. You might be able to get that script to run under [IronPython](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/). From there you *might* be able to use it from another .net language.

Comment: FWIW, PowerShell also uses a functional programming style of "pipes" between items. Moreover, it fully uses and is extensible with .NET... so you might find that pulling an RSS feed with a .NET class is easy, but then sorting and filtering and such are a breeze in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft used to have [Popfly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Popfly) but it was closed a couple of years ago.